# jQuery, only one child affected

Tags: jquery, select, menu, accordion

I'm trying to make a simple accordion menu.

I've got code like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#secondMenu > li > span").click(function () {
        if ($("#secondMenu > li > span").hasClass("icon-square-plus")) {
            $("#secondMenu > li > ul").slideDown();
            $("#secondMenu > li > span").removeClass("icon-square-plus");
            $("#secondMenu > li > span").addClass("icon-square-minus");
        } else {
            $("#secondMenu > li > ul").slideUp();
            $("#secondMenu > li > span").addClass("icon-square-plus");
            $("#secondMenu > li > span").removeClass("icon-square-minus");
        }
    });

    $("#secondMenu > li > ul > li > span").click(function () {
        if ($("#secondMenu > li >  ul > li > span").hasClass("icon-square-plus")) {
            $("#secondMenu > li > ul > li > ul").slideDown();
            $("#secondMenu > li > ul > li > span").removeClass("icon-square-plus");
            $("#secondMenu > li > ul > li > span").addClass("icon-square-minus");
        } else {
            $("#secondMenu > li > ul > li > ul").slideUp();
            $("#secondMenu > li > ul > li > span").addClass("icon-square-plus");
            $("#secondMenu > li > ul > li > span").removeClass("icon-square-minus");
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is, when i click on the span, all items in menu are affected. How to make it only selected one is affected?

Comment: Add a jsfiddle to show whats going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : You are adding and removing class to all matched element, instead you need to do it for clicked element. Use `this` for getting clicked element as shown below

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

$("#secondMenu > li > span").click(function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass("icon-square-plus")) {
        $(this).slideDown();
        // you can chain the addClass and removeClass calls
        $(this).removeClass("icon-square-plus").addClass( "icon-square-minus" );
    } else {
        $(this).slideUp();
        $(this).addClass( "icon-square-plus" ).removeClass( "icon-square-minus" );
    }
});

$("#secondMenu > li > ul > li > span").click(function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass( "icon-square-plus" ) ) {
        $(this).slideDown();
        $(this).removeClass( "icon-square-plus").addClass( "icon-square-minus" );
    } else {
        $(this).slideUp();
        $(this).addClass( "icon-square-plus" ).removeClass( "icon-square-minus" );
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` to select the element which is clicked.
and `parent()` to access parent element to reach `ul` element
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

```
$("#secondMenu > li > span").click(function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass( "icon-square-plus" ) ) {
        $(this).parent().find("ul").slideDown();
        $(this).removeClass( "icon-square-plus" );
        $(this).addClass( "icon-square-minus" );
    } else {
        $(this).parent().find("ul").slideUp();
        $(this).addClass( "icon-square-plus" );
        $(this).removeClass( "icon-square-minus" );
    }
});

$("#secondMenu > li > ul > li > span").click(function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass( "icon-square-plus" ) ) {
        $(this).parent().find("ul").slideDown();
        $(this).removeClass( "icon-square-plus" );
        $(this).addClass( "icon-square-minus" );
    } else {
        $(this).parent().find("ul").slideUp();
        $(this).addClass( "icon-square-plus" );
        $(this).removeClass( "icon-square-minus" );
    }
});
});
```

Comment: everything works great, except i have to add .first(), to not affect all ul's.

Comment: You can also use this `$(this).parent().find("ul:first")`,`$(this).parent().find("ul:eq(0)") ` or `$(this).parent().find("ul").eq(0)` to select the first `ul`

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without the fiddle but a search/replace can help you

e.g. inside of your first click handling method replace

`$("#secondMenu > li > span")` for `$(this)`

`$("#secondMenu > li > ul")` for `$(this).closest("li").find("ul")`

similarly for the second click method

The keyword *this* will constrain the affect to a clicked element only

Comment: closest only search parents element and this case "ul"s are clicked element's brothers so this won't work.

Comment: yeps, noticed it, but decided to explain instead of doing, always a better choice, so changed completely the answer

Comment: i've made it like this: $(this).parent().find("ul").first().slideDown();